# Adding Character in String

Tags: python

If I have a string like this:

```
str = C:\Users\PB\Desktop\Arsiv
```

How can I append character '\' in this string like this:

```
str = C:\\Users\\PB\\Desktop\\Arsiv
```

Comment: [`os.path.normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)?

Comment: `str = C:\Users\PB\Desktop\Arsiv` is not valid Python syntax. Are you sure you tagged the right language?

Comment: `s = "C:\Users\PB\Desktop\Arsiv"; print(re.escape(s))`

Comment: str.replace('\', '\\')

Comment: @vaultah I need to save an image to a folder . I get the path from database and it gives me the first string . So I need to add '\\' character for adding image to the folder

Comment: @Kevin Absolutely I work with python :) .I need to save an image to a folder in PyQt .I am getting path from database and It returns a tuple. QImage class does not accept tuple so I convert it to string .And the str prints the result `str = C:\Users\PB\Desktop\Arsiv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to escape the \ . So, for every instance of a backslash character, replace it with 2 backslash characters.

```
astr.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try raw strings by using an r or R prefix.

```
str = r'C:\\Users\\PB\\Desktop\\Arsiv'
```

Comment: Raw strings are used to not enter escape-sequence hell.